# Django easy captcha input field

Tags: python, django, captcha

At first sorry for my "bad" language ;)

I use Django Easy Captcha and now i must have captcha image for example in bottom of the page and captcha input on the top of the page but CaptchaField() generate me:

```
<img class="captcha" alt="captcha" src="/captcha/image/349b9ed8d5723d390eb33f45028c4805a82ea485/">
<input id="id_captcha_0" type="hidden" value="349b9ed8d5723d390eb33f45028c4805a82ea485" name="captcha_0" autocomplete="off">
<input id="id_captcha_1" type="text" name="captcha_1" autocomplete="off">
```

How to do this? I hope you understand me :)

Sierran